# Facebook Messenger customer chat plugin is not working

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-customer-chat

We have tried to integrate Facebook Customer Plugin to one of our websites. We followed the instructions in the developer documentation, but it‘s not working. At first we get this notifacation with provided url and when you click on it says that „The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID“.

First notification:

[image]

Second notification:

[image]

**We used this codes:**

1)  Facebook SDK

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '1983831301869331',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

2 ) Customer Chat Plugin

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="1983831301869331"
  theme_color="#c43627"
  logged_in_greeting="Sveiki! Kuo galime padëti?"
  logged_out_greeting="Sveiki! Kuo galime padëti?">
</div>
```

Comment: You are embedding the exact same script source twice here. The general JS SDK is a different one.

Comment: So what should I do ? What changes should I make? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do not embed the standard SDK at all, use the Customer Chat version only. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk#install: _“`https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js` requests a version of the Facebook Javascript SDK that includes the Customer Chat SDK. With this URL, you will still be able to access all of the Facebook Javascript SDK plus all features of the Customer Chat SDK.”_

Comment: We tried to add the script that you provided: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js , but unfortunately we get the same message "Invalid App ID". As we understand the problem is with the Facebook app ID, for some reason it doesn't work for us. Maybe there are other possible solutions? Thanks again:)

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/1983831301869331` redirects to `https://www.facebook.com/sblizingas/`, and that is a _page_ … so you did not provide an _app_ id here.

Comment: But we want to connect that FB page with this messenger mailbox_id=1983831301869331 , what kind of app ID we should provide here?

Comment: Do you need any additional functionality out of the “standard” SDK? If not, then just remove the initialization code completely, and use only the code as provided in the docs for the checkbox plugin. Otherwise, insert your actual app id of the app that you are using to provide additional functionality on your site.